# App where one can specify transit city

Tags: transit, mobile-apps

Is there any appication through which I can book tickets where I can specify the transit location and final destination?

Case: I am going on euro trip, for two weeks, the visa does not cover uk, so my plan was to use London as transit city( loophole that says I can roam around the city for without visa if two flights are within 24 hrs), so while leaving for **Singapore(my final destination)**, I am ok to start from any city in Europe as long as the transit city is **London**. Any app that supports this, directs me in a way I can book cheap tickets.

Comment: If you intend to use the transit without visa concession to exit the airport you should be aware of [the current rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423983/uk_visa_requirements_20_april_2015.pdf) (effective 20th April 2015).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not really get why you wanted to do that (I suppose you want to visit London on a transit visa), but to answer your question, most flight search websites have the multi-city search feature (you search for X-London and London-Singapore) or sometimes you can pick your transit location.

- On the web:

[Momondo](http://www.momondo.com) lets you search for your pair origin-destination, and in the left panel of the search results, you can click on one of the suggested transit airports, or uncheck those you don't like.

I tried [expedia](http://www.expedia.com) and [kayak](http://www.kayak.com/flights) and they offer multi-city search. [Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.net), on the other hand, does not seem to offer any of these.

- on Android:

momondo does not seem to offer either transit airport filtering nor multi-city searches. However, the Kayak app offers both airport filtering (including transit airport filtering) and multi-city search.

Comment: I use Momondo quite a lot and it's awesome. The mobile app has no option to select transit airports as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Flights](https://www.google.com/flights/) has functionality where you can filter connecting city. When filtering it will still show you direct flights between your two cities as well as those with a connection in the selected city.

[image]

To maximize your time in London, you may want to use a multi-city search with arrival and depature in London on the same day or across two days. I'd try this because flight search engines generally find the shortest connection, while it sounds like you're interested in the longest one. I'm not sure though, if booking a multi-city flight is handled any differently immigration-wise than a transit flight.